# How to make sure that launch screen is being displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, launch-screen

Even after adding `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)` to appdelegate.swift which I found in another thread, the launch screen of my app is not being displayed on my physical iPhone. However, in the Xcode simulator, it shows up just fine. Is there anything that I can check in the code of my app that might keep the launch screen from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The changes to my launchscreen.storyboard where being cached on my local iphone and I had to delete the app and re-install it via Xcode. From then on the correct launch screen showed up.